# Run sudo commands in Chef resource block

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

To simplify, consider following block in a cookbook (cookbook-test) recipe.

```
 79: bash 'Running sudo test sleep command' do
 80:   user 'root'
 81:   cwd '/tmp'
 82:   code <<-EOH
 83:   sudo sleep 1000
 84:   EOH
 85: end
```

Running this as

> "chef-client -o cookbook-test"

Output:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150813-3835-3kj758" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150813-3835-3kj758" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20150813-3835-3kj758" returned 1
```

I added "sudo sleep" just to exemplify usecase. In real case, we run scripts inside above resource block, and these scripts has sudo commands.

After some debugging found that "bash" and "execute" resource blocks both do not have tty allocated to run commands inside them.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Check your sudoers config file (usually /etc/sudoers) and check if there is a `requiretty` entry in `Defaults`. If so, you could remove that, and your above example could work.

Comment: Yes. Checked that. And yes, it does have mentioned entry.
But unfortunately removing that is not an option as of now.

Comment: Looking for a way with out changing system wide config.

Comment: Does bash or execute resources have any properties that can be set to run commands in an allocated tty? I did not find any in chef documentation till now.

Comment: You already have `user 'root'` set on the resource, so it will run as root.  Why would you need sudo as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing:

Any facility you could use in Chef to run `sudo` with an allocated tty could also be used by anybody *else*, which means the `requiretty` directive in your `sudoers` is effectively useless.  So you might as well just remove it and save yourself the trouble of working around it.

Having said that, here are some ways to work around the problem:

1. Are you able to `ssh` to `localhost` without a password? You could just use `ssh -tt localhost sudo somecomand ...`.
2. You can use the `expect` tool, which is designed for controlling terminal-oriented programs.  Something like `expect -c "spawn sudo somecommand; interact"`.
3. You can use `screen`, with something like `screen sudo somecommand`.